# Rotating animation with moving to switch elements position

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, gsap

I am trying to make this animation in the video [in the video](https://res.cloudinary.com/dtm3d0erl/video/upload/v1670937850/u8sxkzuw8bbgqo0lug37.mp4)
as the video show that we need to switch between two element by rotating and translating them i tried with
rotating and using transform origin but the rotating is done without movement like the video.

Please if anyone can help me with the right keyframe to implement this animation ?

```
<div class='rewinder'>
      <div class='cw'>
        <span >1</span>
      </div>
      <div class='ccw'>
        <div class='circle'></div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.rewinder {
  width: 187px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}
.rewinder > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
.rewinder span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.ccw {
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: animationKF;
}
.cw {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: animationKF;
  transform-origin: right;
}
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes animationKF {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a solution by make gap and rotating just the parent https://codesandbox.io/s/small-dust-ntu0b4?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Well - you put the same animation for both objects, meaning that the distance between them will remain fixed (in the video it seems that they are getting closer at a specific point). To solve this I think that you should create 2 different animations (based on your existing one).

For instance, try to add and attach this animation to `ccw` class

```
@keyframes animationKFAlt {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

I just used values to show that the animation can begin and end with a fixefd position (`0` in our case) and still - during the animation to make adjustments of location (both elements have `relative` position so it's relative to the object current location during the animation

I think you should give it a try and set values and keyframes until you get the desired output